# Is snapping working when changing from NAD83(decimal degree) to NAD83 Zone UTM 11N(meters)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, snapping

I've used the following ESRI snippet  to Convert the display extents in Pixels (at the current map scale) and then return out the map units.

```
public System.Double ConvertPixelsToMapUnits(ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView activeView, System.Int32 pixelUnits)
{
  
  if(activeView == null)
  {
    return -1;
  }
  //Get the ScreenDisplay
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = activeView.ScreenDisplay;

  //Get the DisplayTransformation 
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IDisplayTransformation displayTransformation = screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;

  //Get the device frame which will give us the number of pixels in the X direction
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.tagRECT deviceRECT = displayTransformation.get_DeviceFrame();
  System.Int32 pixelExtent = (deviceRECT.right - deviceRECT.left);

  //Get the map extent of the currently visible area
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IEnvelope envelope = displayTransformation.VisibleBounds;
  System.Double realWorldDisplayExtent = envelope.Width;

  //Calculate the size of one pixel
  if(pixelExtent == 0)
  {
    return -1;
  }
  System.Double sizeOfOnePixel = (realWorldDisplayExtent / pixelExtent);

  //Multiply this by the input argument to get the result
  return (pixelUnits * sizeOfOnePixel);
}
```

and then this to check if the snapping is within tolerance ITolerance which is in Pixels(Example 10 pixels) :

```
Double dblToleranceX;
dblToleranceX = snaptolerance(ITolerance);// call ESRI Snippet 
dblProximity = dblToleranceX;
ouble dblToleranceY = dblToleranceX;
pInputpoint = gpMxDocument.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(intX, intY);
pRectangle.PutCoords(pInputpoint.X - dblToleranceX, pInputpoint.Y - dblToleranceY, pInputpoint.X + dblToleranceX, pInputpoint.Y + dblToleranceY);
pSpatialfilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = gpFeatureWorkSpace.OpenFeatureClass(strFeaturecls);
pSpatialfilter.Geometry = pRectangle;
pSpatialfilter.GeometryField = pFeatureClass.ShapeFieldName;
pFeatureCursor = pFeatureClass.Search(pSpatialfilter, false);
pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature();

if (pFeatureClass.FeatureCount(pSpatialfilter) < 1)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Snapping is not within tolerance");
                    return;
                }
```

The code work perfectly on NAD83(decimal degree)  but does not work  when Changing the data frame's coordinate system  to NAD 83 UTM  Zone 11N (Meters).

Is there a way around this issue in order to make the code work for these kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

I've got an answer from ESRI Canada support and the solution is to use buffer instead of rectangle:

```
   IGeometry buffer;
   ITopologicalOperator topo = (ITopologicalOperator)pInputpoint;
   buffer = topo.Buffer(dblPointDistance);   //(dblProximity);

   pSpatialfilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
   IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass  ;
   pSpatialfilter.Geometry = buffer; //pRectangle , used buffer instead of using rectangle
```